# A "sole trader" - what kind of UK visa & with what requirements?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

What visa for for a non-EEA [sole trader](https://www.gov.uk/set-up-sole-trader)? Is it [Tier 1 (Entrepreneur) visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur)?

If so, do you need at least £50,000 investment funds when you apply for the visa or can you earn it afterwards and show them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An entrepreneur can be a sole trader, but you must have access to investment funds before you apply. You cannot come to the UK to work to earn the funds.

You must also be able to support yourself so in addition to at least £50,000 investment funds you will need more money to pay for your living costs like food and accommodation.